# How to allow users to create an article using form options?

Tags: mediawiki

I recently downloaded a SKin called [Bluesky](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:BlueSky) for my Wiki. I installed the version 1.27.

Now when I click on write an article button I get forwarded to a page that does not allow me to do anything. I added the extension [Page Forms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms) and was able to insert a field for people write a new article tittle.

I wanted my write article page to allow users to after inserting the article tittle, to then be able to select a category and have the form template divided into a few sections. [Here is a sample](https://www.wikihow.com/Special:ArticleCreator?t=ththrth).

How can I set up my template using this Page_Forms extension to lookalike wiki-hows sample?

Comment: I'm confused - there's an "Editar" button that appears to work.

Comment: Yes, but the correct behavior would be for it to open a page for you to insert the tittle and the body of a new article and then submi.

Answer (score 2):

`Special:CreatePage` is provided by the <strike>[Create Page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Create_Page)</strike> WikiHow CreatePage extension, which you [haven't installed](http://www.unilancer.com.br/index.php?title=Especial:Vers%C3%A3o). And in any case that's not where your "Write an article" button points to.

Comment: haha  could you believe after I pasted that link the same revelation came to me when I read that link from WikiHow! haha  but its weird that I installed it and know it's not linked to the "Write an article" button but I can't access the create page feature anyhow! I installed perfectly fine and configured it.. you will see in my special version. Any reason you think why it may not be working?

Comment: Uhh, my bad. Apparently the CreatePage extension on WikiHow and the one on mediawiki.org are completely unrelated. So you have to get the one WikiHow uses (they do not publish their extensions anywhere but the [source code](https://src.wikihow.com/) is available).